# Free storage android

Tags: android, sql, database, storage

I'm building an app which needs to store moderate-to-large (10-100 GB) amounts of data online.
Does android provide any free service to do this?

The best option I am looking for is database storage. I want to be able to interrogate and insert data.

**The second part of my question** is about databases. Is it possible to have an online database that will allow multiple interrogation and possibly multiple insertions at the same time? 
(of course, by "at the same time", I mean I want to have some synchronized piece of data, an user overwrites it, then after waiting for the first user to release it, the second user overwrites it. This waiting is done in background and no error is generated regarding the still-in-use file.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google App Engine probably integrates the best for android as well as gives you 1 gb free and then you can pay for how much you want. Google app-engine will also synchronize your read/write operations for you.

Read more: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/

Comment: Thanks. Much appreciated. I have seen this service before, but I didn't think it's what I needed.